# GCP: Dataflow [unrecognized arguments]: --subnetwork from cloud-shell & Invalid value from console

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-shell

I am trying create dataflow with subnetwork pararameter, but getting these errors 
user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ **unrecognized arguments: --subnetwork**

from Console
**Invalid value for field 'resource.properties.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork**

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run mysqldb_to_bigquery_with_subnet --gcs-location \
gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery \
--region='europe-west1' \
--subnetwork='regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/europe-west1' \
--parameters=driverJars=gs://bucket/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar,driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,connectionURL='jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database?user=user_name&password=password',query='select * from table_name',outputTable=project-name:dataset_name.table_name,bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=gs://bucket_name/dataflow-files/temp-dir
```

Comment: You didn't specify full command in which you gave.

Comment: Updated it @InderRSingh

Comment: gcloud dataflow jobs run, can have following arguments ...only 
(gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) argument JOB_NAME --gcs-location: Must be specified.
Usage: gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME --gcs-location=GCS_LOCATION [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --max-workers | --parameters | --region |
                         --service-account-email | --staging-location | --zone

Answer (score 1):

```
Correct command is still in beta version which you want you use as per documentation.
Command link https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-command-line-intf


gcloud beta dataflow jobs  run 
(gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) argument JOB_NAME --gcs-location
Must be specified.
Usage: gcloud beta dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME --gcs-location=GCS_LOCATION [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --max-workers | --network | --num-workers |
                         --parameters | --region | --service-account-email |
                         --staging-location | --subnetwork |
                         --worker-machine-type | --zone
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  gcloud dataflow jobs run  --> This command can have following arguments only

  (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) argument JOB_NAME --gcs-location:        
  Must be specified.
  Usage: gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME --gcs-location=GCS_LOCATION 
  [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --max-workers | --parameters | --region |
                         --service-account-email | --staging-location | --zone
```

Comment: I am following Dataflow SDK documentation from this page.  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks. It shows subnetwork parameter.

Comment: @BVSKanth Please see answer above and accept it. This is what you need & enjoy.